# Error inflating class textview in android

Tags: java, android, xml

There is this problem that my code is working actually, but i have set some textes to be shown when the Edit text is empty. and when i press the login button my app crashes. and here is the error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML
>   file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
>                      Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099
>   a=1}

here is my xml code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp">

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/input_username_id"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/hint_username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="right" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_password_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_stat_login"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="ورود"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="create an account"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    />
<TextView android:id="@+id/link_forgetpass"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="forget my password"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java code:

```
_emailText = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.input_email));
_passwordText = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.input_password));
_loginButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.btn_login));

_loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
});
public void login() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Login");
    if (!validate()) {
        onLoginFailed();
        return;
    }
    email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("email", email);
    json.addProperty("password", password);

    _loginButton.setEnabled(false);
    WebService.connect(LoginActivity.this, json, "login",layout_for_progressbar);
}
public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;
    String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
       _emailText.setError("Wrong Email");
        valid = false;
    } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
    }
    if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 6 || password.length() > 15) {
        Typeface fontt = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/ir.ttf");
        SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder=new SpannableStringBuilder("Pass between 5 to 16");
        ssbuilder.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("",fontt),0,ssbuilder.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        _passwordText.setError(ssbuilder);
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _passwordText.setError(null);
    }
    return valid;
}
```

and here is my style.xml :

```
 <style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: show how you initialize the two edittext.

Comment: try removing "android:theme="@style/TextLabel""

Comment: @VivekSolanki this was the problem, but now i don't know what is wrong with this style that makes the app crash ?!

Comment: I don't remember the reason exactly, but I had this same problem. So, i removed the style and instead applied these properties in text input layout's property fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was the Parent of the style i was setting it was supposed to be the

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```